# How can I handle relative hrefs in a default page

Tags: javascript, html

My application is hosting a third-party HTML application downloaded using maven-dependency-plugin. The default page is `index.html`, so it can be loaded as `http://server/parent/path` or `http://server/parent/path/index.html`.

The default page loads stylesheets and scripts with relative addresses (e.g. `src="./somescript.js"`). This works when the URL is `http://server/parent/path/index.html`, but fails when it's just `http://server/parent/path`.  The server receives the request as `/parent/somescript.js` and returns 404.

I can edit `index.html` during the build, and one solution is to insert a one-line script:

`<script>if (!/index.html/i.test(window.location.href)) window.location.href += "/index.html";</script>`

This navigates to `index.html`, so that resources are always requested relative to this page.  This works, but it feels wrong.

An orthodox solution might be to insert a `<base>` tag, but this is tricky as I don't know at build time what the full path will be - it might be `http://server/parent/path/` or `http://server/application/parent/path/`. I can't use an absolute base path, and a relative one is going to fail for the same reason as above.

Can anyone suggest a better solution?

Comment: Have you tried doing `src="somescript.js"`? Without the `./`?

Comment: @MaxxikCZ I'm afraid that produces the same requests as `"./somescript.js"`.